# GROUP CONCAT on multiple many-to-many relationsship joins produces duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

So I have a database with a lot of many-to-many relationships. I have my main `items` table, one `class` table and one `class_role` table. An item can have multiple classes and class roles. My desired result is something like this:

```
[{
  ItemId: ...,
  Name: ...,
  Classes: 'Class1, Class2, Class3',
  ClassRoles: 'ClassRole1, ClassRole2'
}...]
```

My current approach is using relationship tables like this: `r_items_classes (Itemid, ClassId), r_items_class_roles (Itemid, ClassRoleId)` and then using a query with GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP_BY like this (`Class` and `ClassRole` are just the respective "Name" field in their corresponding tables):

```sql
SELECT items.ItemId, items.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Class) as Classes FROM items
JOIN r_items_classes ON items.ItemId = r_items_classes.ItemId
JOIN classes ON r_items_classes.ClassId = classes.ClassId
GROUP BY items.Itemid, items.Name
```

now this works perfect for one of the many-to-many relationships. However as soon as I add another one like this for example:

```
SELECT items.ItemId, items.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Class) as Classes, GROUP_CONCAT(ClassRole) as ClassRoles FROM items
JOIN r_items_classes ON items.ItemId = r_items_classes.ItemId
JOIN classes ON r_items_classes.ClassId = classes.ClassId
JOIN r_items_class_roles ON items.ItemId = r_items_class_roles.ItemId
JOIN class_roles ON r_items_class_roles.ClassRoleId = class_roles.ClassRoleId
GROUP BY items.Itemid, items.Name
```

I get duplicate results in the group concats, for example `Classes: 'Class1, Class1, Class2'` or `ClassRoles: 'ClassRole1, ClassRole1, ClassRole1'`. What is the reason for that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use DISTINCT: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT items.ItemId, items.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Class) as Classes,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ClassRole) as ClassRoles
```

However, it can be more performant to do each concatenation separately, by either pre-aggregating or using subqueries.

So, this might be more efficient:

```
select i.*,
       (select group_concat(c.class)
        from r_items_classes ic join
             classes c
             on ic.ClassId = c.ClassId
        where i.ItemId = ic.ItemId
       ) as classes,
       (select group_concat(cr.ClassRole)
        from r_items_class_roles icr join
             class_roles cr
             on icr.ClassId = cr.ClassId
        where i.ItemId = icr.ItemId
       ) as ClassRoles
from items i;
```

This will have better performance especially if the underlying tables have indexes set up correctly.